# Retrieving the value of a variable through a closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have the following module pattern in the javascript for a webpage:

```js
var swf_debugger = swf_debugger || {};

(function($, swf_debugger) {
swf_debugger.pageSetup = (function() {
    var 
    swfType = null,
    formData = {},

    // ... unimportant code continues ...

    initChangeEvents = function() {
        $.each(formElements, function(index, $el) {
            if ($el.hasClass("swfToLoad")) {

                // THIS EVENT IS WHERE I MAKE THE ASSIGNMENT TO 'swfType'
                $el.change(function() { 
                    swfType = $("option:selected", this).val(); 
                    console.log("swfToLoad has triggered");
                    console.log(swfType);
                });
                return;
            }

            // NO ISSUES HERE WITH THESE EVENTS...
            switch($el.prop("tagName")) {
                case "SELECT":
                    $el.change(function() { 
                        formData[$el.attr('id')] = $("option:selected", this).val(); 
                    });
                    break;
                case "INPUT":
                    switch ($el.attr('type')) {
                        case "text" :
                            $el.change(function() { 
                                formData[$el.attr('id')] = $(this).val(); 
                            });
                            break;
                        case "checkbox" :
                            $el.change(function() {
                                formData[$el.attr('id')] = $(this).prop("checked");
                            });
                            break;
                        default:
                    }
                    break;
                default: 
            }
        });
    },

    init = function() {
        $(function() {
            addFormComponents();
            populateDropdowns();
            initCachedData();
            initChangeEvents();
        });
    };

    init();

    return {
        swfType: swfType,
        formData: formData
    };
}());
}($, swf_debugger));
```

---

Essentially I am attaching an event to a series of jquery selected elements, with the callback simply storing the contents of a particular form element (specifically select, text, and checkbox elements) in a variable or an object.

I know my events are attaching properly because when I add `console.log` statements to them I can see them firing. Also, whenever I call `swf_debugger.pageSetup.formData` in the console I see valid contents of the object that each of those events are populating, so those events are doing what they're supposed to.

My troubles are happening whenever I try to access `swf_debugger.pageSetup.swfType` it always returns `null` and I am not understanding why. I know that the particular event feeding this value, is firing and I know that at least within the function scope of the callback, `swfType` is valid because of what is returned in my `console.log` statements. However, whenever I try to access the contents of `swfType` through the closure, (i.e. typing `swf_debugger.pageSetup.swfType` in the console), It always returns null.

I am guessing that I am running into the difference between an objects reference being passed and a variables value being passed, but I am not sure. Can someone please help me along here and explain why `swfType` is always returning `null` through the closure.

Comment: `swf_debugger.pageSetup.formData` doesn't exist; `formData` is a private variable. However, you are returning it as `swf_debugger.passToSwf`, so what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, that was typo... Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is swfType always returning null

Because that's the value which you assigned to the property (gotten from the `swfType` variable which had that value at the time of the assignment). A property is not a reference to the variable assigned to it - you can only assign a value.

What you can do:

- make the object property a getter method which returns the value of the local `swfType` variable whenever it is called
- don't use a variable but assign to the property of the `swf_debugger.pageSetup` object each time

Comment: Thanks that makes sense... I will troubleshoot with your suggestions.